# Confusion: If $C:\{z:|z|=r\} (r\ne1)$, then show $\int_C\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\begin{cases} -2\arctan r & 0<r<1\\ \pi -2\arctan r & 1<r. \end{cases} $

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question :** If $C:\{ z: |z|=r\} \,\,(r\ne1)$, then show that
$$
\int_C\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\begin{cases}
-2\arctan r &\text{if }   0<r<1\\
\pi -2\arctan r &\text{if }   1<r. \end{cases}
$$

*[Exercise-$5$ in Page $262$ of [Ponnusamy-Silverman Book "Complex variables with applications"](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Complex_Variables_with_Applications/GXQQRYUc7gQC?hl=en&gbpv=0)]*

Isn't there a problem in the question? Since Clearly in the first case the answer is $0$, and the second case is far from being $\pi -2\arctan r.$

Comment: There's something missing. "Then show that" _what_ is either $-2\arctan r$ or $\pi - 2\arctan r$, dpending on whether $r < 1$ or $r > 1$?

Comment: Thank you, I just corrected it.

Comment: Okay. That integral is $0$ for $0 < r < 1$ as well as $r > 1$. Are you positive that you didn't misread and it's something like $dx$ or $dy$ or $d\theta$?

Comment: Didn't see the link to the image at first. Yes, definitely a mistake in the book.

Comment: In fact I attached the image of the page

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I am not sure at all that there is an error.

Comment: @JeanMarie How not? The fundamental theorem of complex analysis says the integral is $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Here's a fun exercise: Given that the author clearly made some sort of error.  What do you think is the actual intended problem?

Comment: @RonGordon Idea: semicircle.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer You are right : the result is 0, in both cases (my error : I was only considering pole $i$, forgetting pole $-i$...)

Comment: @DanielFischer: you mean just the arc, not a closed contour.  Interesting.

Comment: @RonGordon Yes, the arc in the upper half-plane. That would give the stated results.